# Error loading Hive driver: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

While connecting Java with Hive I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.scsu.auth.DBAuth.getHIVEAnalysisConnection(DBAuth.java:45)
    at com.scsu.dao.HIVEDAOImpl.getDatabaseTables(HIVEDAOImpl.java:83)
    at com.scsu.facade.HIVEFacadeImpl.getDatabaseTables(HIVEFacadeImpl.java:18)
    at com.scsu.servlets.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

It seems to me that this error is due to missing Hive driver

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you add the Hive JDBC driver to the class path of tomcat or you web application? If not, do that first.

Comment: Then check that your code **explicitly loads the class** > unlike recent JDBC drivers (Type 4.0 and above), the Apache Hive JDBC driver does not auto-register on startup (it's just Type 3, and with limited support of the JDBC API, hence some libraries may refuse to work with it)

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter how can i load class explicitly ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i had already added all the jar files to the class path.

Comment: Actually your stack trace shows a call to `Class.forName(...)` therefore your Java framework tries to load the class explicitly -- but fails. Back to a CLASSPATH issue.